# Running Executable in a different directory in python

Tags: python

I have an executable that pulls an image off of a camera and saves it to the current directory.

I have a python application that calls this executable.  Which is located in a different directory.

What i would like to do is have the python program call the executable, and the executable to run in the current directory that it is in rather than the same directory that the python program is running in.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, simply pass the `cwd` parameter to any of the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) APIs to set the current working directory.

> If `cwd` is not `None`, the child’s current directory will be changed to `cwd` before it is executed. Note that this directory is not considered when searching the executable, so you can’t specify the program’s path relative to `cwd`.

E.g.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['/path/to/prog', 'arg'], cwd=some_dir)
```

Comment: saved my day, thank you. In my case I used: subprocess.Popen(full_path, cwd=exe_directory)